# Hybris is throwing exception during Geolocalization

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm having troubles using points of service in Hybris 6.5
When I run the cronjob or try to geolocate a POS manually I get the following error:

```
ERROR [Geolocalizar Centros de Servicio::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (Geolocalizar Centros de Servicio) [GeocodingJob] Failed to Geocode POS (8796551972856) CelayaPOS Error: null Address: Carr. Ind Celaya-VillagrÃ¡n km 3.57, 38158, Celaya, MX
```

I've debuged the code and the parta throwing the error is the following:

```
final PointOfServiceModel pos = context.getData();
    final DistanceUnawareLocation location = new DistanceUnawareLocation(pos);

    try
    {
        final GPS e1 = this.geoServiceWrapper.geocodeAddress(location);//Throws Error
```

The following is the error stacktrace when I click the geolocate POS icon:

```
 [exec] de.hybris.platform.storelocator.exception.GeoServiceWrapperException
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.storelocator.impl.GoogleMapTools.geocodeAddress(GoogleMapTools.java:206)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.storelocator.impl.GoogleMapsServiceWrapper.geocodeAddress(GoogleMapsServiceWrapper.java:56)
 [exec]     at com.mabe.core.pos.backoffice.PointOfServiceGeolocationAction.perform(PointOfServiceGeolocationAction.java:62)
 [exec]     at com.hybris.cockpitng.actions.impl.DefaultActionRenderer.perform(DefaultActionRenderer.java:241)
 [exec]     at com.hybris.cockpitng.actions.impl.DefaultActionRenderer.lambda$createEventListener$2(DefaultActionRenderer.java:450)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3163)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3133)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3075)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1853)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1625)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1328)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:606)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:482)
 [exec]     at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:490)
 [exec]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
 [exec]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at com.hybris.backoffice.mobile.filter.BackofficeMobileFilter.doFilter(BackofficeMobileFilter.java:63)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:141)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:301)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:390)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:141)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at com.hybris.cockpitng.modules.spring.filter.ExternalModuleContextClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(ExternalModuleContextClassLoaderFilter.java:44)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter.doFilter(DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter.java:90)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d468805.invoke(<generated>)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a8cac040.doFilter(<generated>)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DataSourceSwitchingFilter.doFilter(DataSourceSwitchingFilter.java:70)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.doFilter(RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.java:101)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.TenantActivationFilter.doFilter(TenantActivationFilter.java:88)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:201)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:179)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
 [exec]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
 [exec]     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
 [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm using OOTB hybris store locator functionality. My apikey is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean that it could not interpret or geocode the address. Check if "Carr. Ind Celaya-VillagrÃ¡n km 3.57, 38158, Celaya, MX" is correct.

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought. I'm pretty sure that the address is correct. The thing is that I am getting the same error with all pointa of service in backiffice. It used to worked fine when we had 6.0.23 hybris version.  The error appeared when we migrate to hybris 6.5. I'm not sure, but there should not be problem because the method and the service is OOTB functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The real exception cause depends on the used `GeoWebServiceWrapper` implementation.
Do you use OOTB implementation?

Actually, GeoServiceWrapperException should contain the real reason which should be logged but it's `null` in your case (`CelayaPOS Error: null`)

Could you please provide stacktrace to have more details?

Comment: Hi Ihar. I've added to the post the stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Hector.
The only possible reason for the error you got is an unexpected response for Google Maps API.
I would like to advise to try to check response body to ensure that it's a root cause. Unfortunately, due to implementation, there is no simple way to adjust restTemplate instance to add logging interceptor to it, so debug is the simplest way to go. 
Try to set up breakpoint at de.hybris.platform.storelocator.impl.FirstPlacemarkWinsGoogleResponseParser. (before response input stream is closed).

Sorry for suggestions instead of concrete answer, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error in my hybris instance where the geolocation job was working before.
I debugged everything and found out that hybris is making calls without an google api key, this causes the bad request.